# Position absolute not working inside ScrolView in React native

Tags: react-native

I was trying to position a button on the bottom right of the screen like the picture below:

[image: What I wanted]

So, basically I had a Scrollview with the button inside like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView,View,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
import CreditCardList from '../Components/credit-cards/CreditCardList';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Button from '../Components/common/Button';

// Styles
import styles from './Styles/CreditCardScreenStyle'
import CreditCardScreenStyle from './Styles/CreditCardScreenStyle';

class CreditCardScreen extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>         
          <CreditCardList />
          <TouchableOpacity  style={CreditCardScreenStyle.buttonStyle}>
              <Icon name="md-add"  size={30} color="#01a699" />
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

My styles:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { ApplicationStyles } from '../../Themes/'

export default StyleSheet.create({
  ...ApplicationStyles.screen,
  container:{
    marginTop: 50,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  buttonStyle:{
    width: 60,  
    height: 60,   
    borderRadius: 30,  
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',          
  //  backgroundColor: '#ee6e73',                                    
    position: 'absolute',                                          
    bottom: 0,                                                    
  //  right: 10, 
  }
})
```

The problem is that the absolute positioning does not work at all when the button is inside the ScrollView. But...If I change the code to look like this:

```
import CreditCardScreenStyle from './Styles/CreditCardScreenStyle';

class CreditCardScreen extends Component {

  render () {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView >         
          <CreditCardList />
        </ScrollView>

        <TouchableOpacity  style={CreditCardScreenStyle.buttonStyle}>
              <Icon name="md-add"  size={30} color="#01a699" />
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Then it works !! Whaat? Why? How? I don't understand why this is happening and I would appreciate any information about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be inconvenient but is just how RN works.

Basically anything that's inside the ScrollView (in the DOM/tree) will scroll with it. Why? Because `<ScrollView>` is actually a wrapper over a `<View>` that implements touch gestures.

When you're using `position: absolute` on an element inside the ScrollView, it gets absolute positioning relative to its first relative parent (just like on the web). Since we're talking RN, its first `relative` parent is always its first parent (default positioning is `relative` in RN). First parent, which in this case is the `View` that's wrapped inside the `ScrollView`.

So, the only way of having it "fixed" is taking it outside (in the tree) of the `ScrollView`, as this is what's actually done in real projects and what I've always done.

Cheers.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I think that's how it's supposed to work. Elements inside scrollview are absolute in the context of their container only, but relative to screen window because elements inside a scrollview are supposed to well, scroll :-)

Answer (score 4):

i suggest to use "react-native-modal".
you can not use `position: 'absolute'` to make elements full size in `ScrollView`
but you can do it by
putting that element in modal wrapper.

below are two examples. first one doesnt work but the second one works perfectly.

first way (doesnt work):

```
const app = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState('relative')
  return(
    <ScrollView>
      <Element style={{position: position}}/>
      <Button
      title="make element fixed"
      onPress={()=> setPosition('absolute')}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

second way (works perfectly):

```
const app = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)
  return(
    <ScrollView>
      <Modal isModalVisible={isModalVisible}>
        <Element style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
      </Modal>
      <Button
      title="make element fixed"
      onPress={()=> setIsModalVisible(true)}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked:
before:

```
   <View>
      <VideoSort FromHome={true} />
      <StatisticShow style={{position:'absulote'}}/>
   </View>
```

after:

```
  <View>
    <ScrollView>
      <VideoSort FromHome={false} />
      </ScrollView>
    <View style={{position:'relative'}}>
       <StatisticShow style={{position:'absulote'}}/>
    </View>
  </View>
```